# Where do I put adverbial expressions and other phrases in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntax

I know Chinese use the sequence S O V. I also know place follows time, for instance in these ways: t(ime), p(lace)

- S tp V O
- tp S V O
- t S p V O

Where do I put further phrases, like adverbial expressions in a Chinese sentence?

Comment: further phrases = adverbial expressions that are not t,p ?, for discussion of relative order between different adverbial adjuncts see e.g. previous question: The word order of co-existing adverbs in a sentence.

Comment: b/a S？＂实用现代汉语语法＂５１８页 一、只能位于主语前的状语 只能位于主语前的状语限于限制性的，主要是有＂关于＂、＂至于＂构成的介词短语。例如：１关于他，这里有不少类似小说一样的传说。２关于明年的计划，我们以后再讨论。３考‌​试的范围我可以告诉你们，至于考试的题目，那当然要保密喽！４在月底以前你一定要给我一个答复，至于同意还是不同意，那是你的自由。当谓语中包含其他结构比较复杂的描写状语‌​时，不包含介词的处所词语也要放在主语前。例如：５院子里，孩子们你追我赶地玩着。６池塘旁边，一群白鹅一跛一跛的迈着方步。二、只能位于主语后的状语 只能位于主语后的状语包括：绝大多数描写性的状语，部分限制性的状语。描写性的状语绝大多数只能位于主语后，只有极个别的可位于主语前。例如：１像只燕子似地，小红在林子里‌​一会儿飞到这儿，一会飞到那儿。２一脚他就把球踢出了大门外。３慢慢地大家对我不那么客气了。（＂慢慢地＂有时间意义）下列限制状语位于主语后：（一）副词，表示语气的及部‌​分时间副词除外（见本节之＂三＂）；（二）少数不包含介词的处所词语，在口语中要放在主语后，这时，谓语部分一定很简短。例如：１客人们请屋里坐！２老人炕上睡，炕上吃。（‌​三）有＂把、被、将、叫、让、给、管、替、离＂等构成的介词状语。例如：你把那本书递给我。２这个孩子管他叫叔叔３北大离清华不远。４你‌​给我买点东西来。

Comment: did users take off points from question b/c of "SOV" which is later corrected to SVO occurring 3 times, of course sometimes O can be put before V (fronted object/前置宾语)

Comment: 三、既可以在主语前也可以在主语后出现的状语（主要是限性的状语）１。表示时间的词语，包括时间词及下列副词：忽然、突然、马上、立刻、回头、一时、起初、慢慢地等；２。多数介词短语；３。表示语气的副词；４。极个别的描写性状语（见本节之＂二＂）。上述四类状语一般情况下多位于主语后。例如：１你明天来吧。２我忽然想起一件事来。３我想趁这个工夫跟老人聊聊。４阿丹经常在宿舍里听录音。５这几个月小燕确实付出了不少劳动。６听他这么一说，小明简直不敢相信自己的耳朵了。在下列情况下，此类状语要放在主语前：１。状语承接前文，有连接句子、篇章的作用。例如：１头天晚上他很晚才睡。第二天起得很迟。２这时服务员停掉广播赶回来了。３我们每天上午上四节课。除了上课以外，我们还常常出去参观。４在这些事实面前，大家又受到了一次教育。２。特别强调此类状语的作用。例如：１明天上午你来开会，别望了！２突然，周围一片黑暗。３明明你错了，为什么不承认呢？４难道我说得不对么？５对他，我从来没有什么好印象。６在家里，我看不下去书。

Comment: ３。状语修饰不止一个分句。例如：１天一擦黑，她就把后门关上了，把鸡窝堵上了。２原来，我仗着是个老杭州，打算在杭州呆三天，订了一天旅游、两天参观市区的计划。３进城后，他入了党，提了干，为革命做了很多工作。４在实践中，我们的医学知识由少到多，医疗技术逐步提高。５在中国共产党的领导下，中国人民推翻了三座大山，建立了中华人民共和国。４，对比或列举不同时间或不同条件下发生的事情。例如：１明天我们要去长城，不能去你那儿了，以后再去看你呢。２从前他是一个工人，最近才当上干部。３在业务上，我教你；在思想上，你多帮助我。４对工作，他精益求精；对困难，他从不退缩；对朋友，他满腔热情；对自己，他严格要求。５。当状语结构比较复杂或音节很多时，以位于主语前为宜。例如：１当暴风雨快到来的时候，龙梅的爸爸就骑马去找孩子和羊群。２在我上大学的前一天，田大婶给我讲了她以前的痛苦生活。３对每一个具体的困难，我们都要采取认真对待的态度。４根据开荒造林季节的要求和生产的特点，参加造林队的知青在开荒造林季节要保证在场劳动。状语位于主语前最主要的原因是承接上文，起句子，篇章的连接作用。上述原因２－５常常同时都具有句子，篇章的连接作用。

Answer (score 1):

adverbial adjuncts (状语) always premodify the predicate which can be a verb, adjective or other predicate. These have to be distinguished from complements (补语）。The latter always postmodify the predicate (verb or adjective) .

quote from 外国人实用汉语语法（ISBN ７－８００５２－０６７－６）第无节 状语 （Adverbial Adjuncts）
一，什么叫状语（Definition）

在动词谓语前边的状语 （adverbial adjuncts premodifying the verb predicate：状语－－－中心语（动词谓语）

Adverbial adjunct ＋ modified word （verb predicate）
他 昨 天 参加了一个招待会。

我们 那 边 看看。

他 很 关心大家的健康。

我 只 有一本汉语语法书。etc。

在形容词谓语前边的状语：
（Adverbial adjuncts premodifying adjective predicate）：
状语－－－中心语（形容词谓语）

adverbial adjunct ＋ head word （adjective predicate）

他 非 常 谨慎。

他对人 很 热情。

他说话的声音 不 大。

在其他谓语前边的状语 （adverbial adjuncts premodifying other types of predicates）：

他 已 经 二十八岁了。

今天大概十七号。

二，状语的语法特点（Grammatical features）

（一）状语一定要在中心语前边 （The adverbial adjunct always precedes the head word）

（三）状语后边常带结构助词＂地（de）＂（The structural particle 地 is often attached to the adverbial adjunct）